# Bijections, how to prove?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm not sure how bijection and modularity are related, I know that bijection is one to one and onto.

So my questions are;

Is $f(x) \equiv x^{−1} \pmod{p}$ a bijection from $\{1,...,p−1\}$ to $\{1,...,p−1\}$?
And how about $f(x) = x^2 \pmod{p}$?

How do I prove these?

Comment: They aren't "related"...bijection is a term given to a map of sets, but this is what you are given in the question!

Answer (score 0):

The first question is equivalent to asking whether all elements of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ have a unique multiplicative inverse. The answer is yes iif $p$ is prime; the inverse can be computed by the extended euclidean algorithm.